# How do I find the the win rate of each team?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have df that contains

| homeTeam | AwayTeam | homeTeam Score | AwayTeam Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 3 | 1 |
| C | A | 5 | 3 |
| A | C | 0 | 1 |
| A | B | 2 | 1 |
| B | A | 0 | 1 |
| C | A | 4 | 3 |
| A | C | 0 | 1 |
| A | B | 0 | 1 |

I want to find the home vs away win rate for each team like this:

| Team | Home win rate | away win rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 50% | 0% |
| C | 100% | 100% |
| A | 25% | 25% |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"homeTeam":["B","C","A","A","B","C","A","A"],
     "AwayTeam":["A","A","C","B","A","A","C","B"],
     "homeTeam Score":[3,5,0,2,0,4,0,0],
     "AwayTeam Score":[1,3,1,1,1,3,1,1]})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this can be shorter but anyway:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"homeTeam":["B","C","A","A","B","C","A","A"],
     "AwayTeam":["A","A","C","B","A","A","C","B"],
     "homeTeam Score":[3,5,0,2,0,4,0,0],
     "AwayTeam Score":[1,3,1,1,1,3,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.loc[df["homeTeam Score"]>df["AwayTeam Score"], "result"] = "home wins"
df.loc[df["homeTeam Score"]<df["AwayTeam Score"], "result"] = "away wins"
df.loc[df["homeTeam Score"]==df["AwayTeam Score"], "result"] = "ties"

df2 = df.groupby(["homeTeam", "result"]).size().rename("number_of_games").reset_index()

result = pd.pivot_table(data=df2, values="number_of_games", index="homeTeam", columns="result").fillna(0)
result = (result.div(result.sum(axis=1), axis=0)*100)

# result    away wins  home wins
# homeTeam                      
# A              75.0       25.0
# B              50.0       50.0
# C               0.0      100.0
```